# Advanced search can not make it work

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to implement an advanced search on all microposts (by keyword and by purpose -dropdown options-) but I can not even write to the database searches.  I guess my problems could be: models construction, collection_select set up, or controller (mostly everywhere).
routes.rb has all resources, but :searches is not nested

new.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for @search do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :keywords %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :keywords %>
    <%= f.label :purpose_id %><
    <%= f.collection_select :purpose_id, Micropost.order(:purpose), :id, :purpose_id, include_blank: true %>
    <%= f.submit 'Buscar' %>
<% end %>
```

searches_controller.rb:

```
    class SearchesController < ApplicationController

def new
    @search = Search.new
end

def create
      @search = Search.new(params[:search])
      if @search.save
        redirect_to @search
      else
        redirect_to root_url
      end
    end def show
    @search = Search.find(params[:id])
end

    private
    def search_params
      params.require(:search).permit(:keywords, :purpose_id)
    end
```

schema.db:

```
create_table "microposts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "content"
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "picture"
    t.string "purpose"
    t.index ["user_id", "created_at"], name: "index_microposts_on_user_id_and_created_at"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_microposts_on_user_id"
end

create_table "searches", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "keywords"
    t.integer "purpose_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

Error from console:

Processing by SearchesController#create as HTML Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"wA3FRz....6Kg==", "search"=>{"keywords"=>"", "purpose_id"=>"18"}, "commit"=>"Buscar"}

Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError (ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError):

app/controllers/searches_controller.rb:8:in `create'

Comment: What is the error that you get when you try to save? Perhaps it's just failing some validations you have? If you add `puts @search.errors.inspect` after `@search.save` can you see what is output in the console window?

Comment: In new.html.erb under Purpose drop down button I see every purpose for each micropost. When a micropost is created, the user has to choose between two purposes (Offer/Demand). When I click Search after selecting one (ie. Offer) it shows in console: Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"9..w==", "search"=>{"keywords"=>"", "purpose_id"=>"19"}, "commit"=>"Buscar"}

Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError (ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError):

app/controllers/searches_controller.rb:8:in `create'

Comment: Searches database registers no record, it is empty

Comment: app/controllers/searches_controller.rb:8:in `create' corresponds to: @search = Search.new(params[:search])

Comment: Great, thanks - so probably what you need to look at is the permit/require section of your controller. Can you please edit your question and add that there? Also, I should have mentioned... for clarity, it's really hard to read code in comments - the formatting is awful. Could you possibly edit your question and add this stuff there instead? it's kind of part of your question, and much easier to read that way! Next time I'll mention it when I ask :P :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the raw `param`s directly into your model's constructor, rather than `search_params` where you require/permit specific parameters. `search_param` needs to be invoked to do anything.

The line

```
@search = Search.new(params[:search])
```

needs to be

```
@search = Search.new(search_params)
```

Comment: Thanks, now database is recording searches !! But retrieves only one micropost, the one I select from the dropdown button "purpose". I am not seeing the big picture here...my mistake...